# android search nearby bus stop google api

Tags: java, android

I have android project for searching nearby bus stops i have this url:
http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/query.exe/dot?performLocating=2&tpl=stop2csv&stationProxy=yes&look_maxdist=250&look_x=6112550&look_y=49610700

i write in the code

```
  StringBuilder sb = newStringBuilder("http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/query.exe/dot?performLocating=2&tpl=stop2csv&stationProxy=yes &");
                   sb.append("look_maxdist=250");sb.append("look_x="+mLatitude");sb.append("look_y="+mLongitude");
```

where mLatitude and mLongitude are for current user location

now the response in not json but http response

```
6,113204;49,610280;200403005;Belair, Sacré-Coeur;http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/stboard.exe/dn?L=vs_stb&input=200403005&start 

6,112260;49,612644;200403002;Belair, Archiducs;http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/stboard.exe/dn?L=vs_stb&input=200403002&start
```

or as link maybe

```
id=A=1@O=Belair, Sacré-Coeur@X=6,113204@Y=49,610280@U=82@L=200403005@B=1@p=1481807866; 

id=A=1@O=Belair, Archiducs@X=6,112260@Y=49,612644@U=82@L=200403002@B=1@p=1481807866;
```

the question is how i can continue with this result to ge coordinates (6,113204,49,610280)and put marker on the map
here is the link 
https://data.public.lu/en/datasets/arrets-de-transport-public-et-departs-en-temps-reel/

Answer (score 0):

From this url you get the id for the request.

http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/hafas/query.exe/dot?performLocating=2&tpl=stop2csv&stationProxy=yes &look_maxdist=250&look_x=6112550&look_y=49610700

Now you received response as below :

> id=A=1@O=Belair,%20Sacré-Coeur@X=6,113204@Y=49,610279@U=82@L=200403005@B=1@p=1459856195

Now, append received response with below url and you will get the response in json.

http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/restproxy/departureBoard?accessId=cdt&format=json&

For example:

[http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/restproxy/departureBoard?accessId=cdt&format=json&id=A=1@O=Belair,%20Sacré-Coeur@X=6,113204@Y=49,610279@U=82@L=200403005@B=1@p=1459856195](http://travelplanner.mobiliteit.lu/restproxy/departureBoard?accessId=cdt&format=json&id=A=1@O=Belair,%20Sacr%C3%A9-Coeur@X=6,113204@Y=49,610279@U=82@L=200403005@B=1@p=1459856195)

Comment: thenks for answering